# How to manage different http requests weight with resilience policy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

We are using a rest API service that we need to collect data over the time. This service expose various endpoints and each one consume a fixed number of credits per request. We have a minutely credits usage limit that we cannot exceed.

So for example we have this variables:

- *Minutely maximum:* 1000 credits
- *Request 1 necessary:* 20 credits
- *Request 2 necessary:* 1 credits

Our .NET 8 Worker Service is continuously ask for new data and we don't know how much requests and of which type (req 1 or 2) it will perform.

How can limit the requests in order to not exceed the 1000 credits per minute limit? How we can assign a weight per request based on the url?

We tried something with `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience` with the `FixedWindowRateLimiter` but unfortunately there isn't a way to manage the limit with a custom weight per request.

Comment: All `Acquire` methods allow requesting more than 1 permits. What does your current code look like?

Comment: My code now is completely wrong because it relies on `FixedWindowRateLimiter ` but it's not optimized due to different request credits usage.

```builder.Services.AddHttpClient("twelve",x => new HttpClient())
    .AddResilienceHandler("twelve_rate_limit", static builder =>
    {
        builder.AddRateLimiter(new FixedWindowRateLimiter(
            new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
            {
                PermitLimit = 987 / (20 + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1),
                Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                QueueLimit = int.MaxValue,
            }));
    });```

Answer (score 0):

The rate limiter with Fixed window limit won't help in your case as it allows a specific number of requests to be made within a defined time interval. your requirement is to serve the request based on credit and you have fixed credit per minute.to achive that you could use custom code. below is the sample code:

```
class WeightedRateLimiter {
    private readonly int maxCreditsPerMinute;
    private int creditsUsedThisMinute;
    private DateTime minuteWindowStart;

    public WeightedRateLimiter(int maxCreditsPerMinute) {
        this.maxCreditsPerMinute = maxCreditsPerMinute;
        this.creditsUsedThisMinute = 0;
        this.minuteWindowStart = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public bool TryConsumeCredit(int creditsNeeded) {
        if ((DateTime.UtcNow - minuteWindowStart).TotalMinutes >= 1) {
            creditsUsedThisMinute = 0;
            minuteWindowStart = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        if ((creditsUsedThisMinute + creditsNeeded) <= maxCreditsPerMinute) {
            creditsUsedThisMinute += creditsNeeded;
            return true; 
        }

        return false; 
    }
}
```

Use this code to check the request:

```
var rateLimiter = new WeightedRateLimiter(1000); 

if (rateLimiter.TryConsumeCredit(20)) {
    // Request 1
} else {
    // logic to handle if limit exceed
}

if (rateLimiter.TryConsumeCredit(1)) {
    // Request 2
} else {
    // logic to handle if limit exceed
}
```